# How to remove vertical lines in an asp.net gridview

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview

I am working on an asp.net C# webforms gridview. This gridview was created entirely from the code behind and populated. I have to add four buttons at the footer of this control. I am wondering whether there is a way to remove horizontal lines from the footer as well as to make the entire footer as a single cell? Currently I am adding buttons in the footer as shown below.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
{
   e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(myButton);
}
```

This adds buttons within a cell. I would like to have the footer without the vertical lines and all four buttons close to each other and at the center.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain your scenario a little bit more...maybe if you post a picture of your current result vs the desired one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `colspan` to the GridView row in the `OnRowDataBound` event.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    //span the first cell 3 columns
    e.Row.Cells[0].ColumnSpan = 3;

    //remove the next cell twice
    e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(1);
    e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(1);
}
```

Not sure about your horizontal lines, it could be css, but that is impossible to say for sure without more info.

Comment: Instead of RemoveAt, I made e.Row.Cells[1 to 3].Visible = false;